# Why in runtime the app have java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactivemongo/api/bson/SafeBSONWriter

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I have a simple service as an example:

```
object SimpleService {

  def findById(id: String, col: MongoCollections): Future[Option[Simple]] =
    collection(col).flatMap(c => c.find(selectorId(id)).one[Simple])

}
```

where the `Simple`:

```
case class Simple(@Key("_id")id: String, name: String,)

object Simple{
 implicit val eventHandler: BSONDocumentHandler[Simple] = 
   Macros.using[MacroOptions.ReadDefaultValues].handler[Simple]
}
```

Then I have written some integration tests and everything works fine when I run the tests. I can do all CRUD operations in the tests.

But I added a server with some simple API and when I use a method `findById` from `SimpleService`

I have an error in runtime only:

```
Uncaught error from thread [SimpleServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]: reactivemongo/api/bson/SafeBSONWriter, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[SomeServer]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactivemongo/api/bson/SafeBSONWriter
```

FYI: `SafeBSONWriter` is a private trait and object in the library.

Could you suggest where to look?

Comment: Check your runtime environement has the same JAR. There a JAR must be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "reactivemongo-bson-api" dependency, this will solve the issue